# Dynamic UI ListView

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android

If I have a xml file linear layout with CheckBox, TextView and ImageView and want this to display as scrollable list, having different name and different pictures in every rom of ListView , how can I do it. I am really confused, can you please help me understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is a custom list row. There are plenty of examples around:

http://appfulcrum.com/?p=311

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/